# Why do my scanned images have lines across them?

Tags: prints, scanning

As you can see in the example, my scanned images have horizontal and vertical lines across them. They are very noticeable in dark areas of the image. The original print is a 4x6 matte finish print. Scanned using a very basic [HP PSC 1210](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008NGIB) - 600 x 2,400 dpi scan resolution, 19,200 dpi interpolated, 36-bit color.

I am using Windows 7 scan wizard, and have tried 200dpi, and 1200dpi. I could adjust the images in Photoshop, but am trying to scan it correctly the first time.

Please tell me what my issue is, the original print finish, scanner, settings, anything else?

[image: Jay Lance Photography - this dog photo is for you!]

Comment: @Jay Lance Photography - Cute dog photo, just for you!

Comment: Looks like a hardware issue to me. I often see these lines when using real cheap scanners. Try a higher end unit?

Comment: I've got to go along with @Jakub -- in my experience, the scanning unit on HP's MFPs (and I've owned a few over the years) are generally horrid, and that "through a screen" effect is almost always the result. Almost anything's an upgrade. I don't do a lot of flatbed scanning these days, so I'm using the scanner built into an Epson NX420 MFP (at $45, it was cheaper than a dedicated flatbed), and it's at least as good as the Perfection 1600 unit I paid through the nose for about 10 years back.

Comment: @Stan Rogers - Thanks for the tip. I knew coming in that it was a pile of junk:) But it is the only pile of junk I have so I thought I'd try to fix it before buying new. Looks like I'll have to get a new one!

Answer (score 3):

If you still have the negatives available, I would get my hands on scanner that can scan them. Scanning prints is bound to reduce quality and dynamic range, sometimes less, sometimes more.

Comment: I do have the negatives for some of my prints, I do not have a negative scanner though. I'll have to look into that.