# What are these lines through my images (on the negatives and the prints)?

Tags: film, aberration, scratches

I have these lines or streaks across many of the images on this roll I had developed. I can see the same lines on the negatives as well as the prints. The lines are in the exact same spot across I believe the entire roll. It was shot on Kodak Ektar 100 film(within date).

If you can tell me how to avoid, limit, or stop producing the lines I would appreciate that as well.

[image: Pizza place streaks]
[image: Hanging Out]

Comment: Note, this is not in regards to the issue described in this other question, as that pertained to scanning only: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15149/why-do-my-scanned-images-have-lines-across-them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Back in the day, would get streaks like that if you had an old, reusable 35mm cartridge that had dirt or dust on the film slit. So as your camera rolled it back into the cartridge, the dust would scrape along the emulsion and your whole roll was ruined.

Also seen this if someone pulls the film out of the cartridge, rather than popping end of cartridge off (this is another reason to roll your leader into roll).

Finally, if processed on a machine, it could be something similar but on the developing side, where these machines print on massive rolls and cut the images at the last stage...so something dragging along the paper could produce a similar defect across many images.

Take a look at your negatives and see if they are damaged, if not, take a deep breath and get them developed elsewhere.

Comment: Two more places to check -- the pressure plate (which can scratch the back of the film base, and given the out-of-focus nature of the lines, that's whee I'd put my money) and the left and right lips of the light box.

Comment: Cranking the film back into the cartridge too fast after exposing the roll could sometimes put too much pressure on the film and cause the back of the film to be scratched on the pressure plate at the point where it first contacted the plate coming off the takeup spool in the camera. Using a steady, deliberate pace to wind the film back into the cannister is usually all that is needed to avoid that particular problem.