# What are these streaks in negative scans I got back from a lab?

Tags: troubleshooting, film, artifacts, negative-scanner

I'm a beginner that's getting back into film photography after many years. I just received scans of my negatives and noticed some of them have streaking while others do not. I feel like this may have happened when the film was developed but I'm unsure. Perhaps it's the camera, the film or something I did? The film is Kodak Tri-x 400.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you develop the negatives yourself? If so, did you use any wetting agent, squeegee the negatives, how did you dry them etc.  And are all the streaks in the same orientation?

Comment: Look at the actual film.  Are these artifacts on the negatives too, or just in the scans?

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I sent the film to a Los Angeles photo lab to be developed and scanned. Some photos have the streaks and some do not. The streaks appear uniform. Based on the feedback, I'd guess it's the scanner as well. I'll be getting the negatives and a contact sheet in the mail soon so I'll definitely look closely at those. Thank you!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do my scanned images have lines across them?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15149/why-do-my-scanned-images-have-lines-across-them)

Comment: @thomasrutter you can if it is an A4 scanner with a negative scanning attachment (ie lightbox). Epson V370. HP Scanjet G3110. He didn't specify the type of scanner either.

Answer (score 2):

Because the streaks are all in a perfect vertical orientation my bet is that the scanner is to blame.  While it's possible for streaks to happen while processing the negatives I feel that's pretty unlikely to result in the same thing.  And it won't be the camera.

Possibly the scanner was not properly cleaned or maintained.

The only way to be sure is to scan some of the same negatives with someone else, using a different scanner.  If the streaks are no longer there you can confirm that it was a scanning issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same problem.  I bought a 100' roll at Henry's last Winter when it was half price.  I wonder if they know something  we don't.
Tried  Ilford HP5, Fomapan 400 no problem.  Went back to tri-x  and the streaks are back. Definitely the film is problematic

Answer (score 0):

As noted, since the streaks are on some scans but not others, and presuming they don't show in the actual film, they occurred during scanning.

It's very likely the lab had some ripple in the power supply for the scanner, and if that's the case, they'll have had other customers affected.  You should contact the lab, show them the image you included above and any others, and point out that this problem seems to be in their scanner.  At the least, they should offer to rescan your negatives for free.

This may also be a hint to start processing your own negatives: you don't need a full darkroom, and you can buy the equipment needed (barring chemicals) for around $100 -- that's probably less than the cost of paying for process and scan (with shipping priced in) on five rolls.  I learned to process my own film at age nine -- it's easy.  There's a lot to know, but you don't have to know all of it to process Tri-X.

Once you have negatives, you can scan with a DSLR or even a top end smart phone camera, or you can buy a used film scanner for another $100 or less -- and then, if there's a problem, you can solve it yourself instead of having to ask how someone else screwed up.

Answer (score -1):

some say its the static charge released by the holding tape on the 120 roll films, when pulled away from the backing paper in the dark there is always a static charge that is released, possible film fogging causing streaks..

Comment: This isn't fog from a light source of any kind -- it's too regular and not broad enough.  This is a scanning fault.