# How can I remove white stripes from an old photo without losing detail?

Tags: photo-editing, image-quality, restoration

I have this old photo:

[image: Before]

I want to remove these vertical white stripes from it.

I have managed to remove it by using the darken blend mode with motion blur, but as you can see down below, I have lost a lot of details that I couldn't retrieve by sharpening the image. I want to preserve as much detail as I can.

[image: After]

Comment: See also: [Why do my scanned images have lines across them?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15149/why-do-my-scanned-images-have-lines-across-them)

Comment: If the lines are artifacts from scanning the photo then this answer: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/33472/15871 to this question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23445/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-texture-from-a-scanned-textured-photo-paper should also work.

Comment: If the stripes are from a reflective surface, I believe there are sprays to dull the surface specifically for scanning. (Matte spray)

Answer (score 7):

By doing a quick edit using Fourier Transform as described in this [Imagemagick tutorial](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fourier/#noise_removal) I managed to considerable reduce the annoying effect when viewed at 100%.

[image: Edit using Fourier Transforms]

A more thorough edit using this method might provide better results, but the repeating pattern appears so often that some areas of the picture are basically left without any detail.

Answer (score 4):

At a pixel level, you want to blur the lighter pixels horizontally, without blurring the picture as a whole too much. I took two times two similar steps in Adobe Photoshop to create the picture below.

The first two steps:

1. I selected the white colors using the "Select color range" tool, selecting an almost white pixel and using a large range to select similar colors.
2. Next, I used the custom filter (Menu: Filter, Other, Custom Filter) with all zero's except on the center row, I used the weights: 1, 2, 3, 2, 1. And a scale factor of 9 (the sum of the weights).

The effect of this is that the most white vertical stripes are averaged (blurred). Every pixel becomes a weighted average of its neighbors on the left and right.

In the second iteration, I did the same for the picture as a whole:

3. Deselect the previous selection (ctrl-d)
4. Repeat the same filter as before on the picture as a whole.

The result is this:

[image: Horizontal blur]